# How to remove specific exceptions?

Tags: vb.net, exception

I have an application that shows a specific error of `"Cannot convert string'' to Decimal"`. I want to remove this error. I don't want to show `"Cannot convert string'' to Decimal"` but other can be shown. How should program my `Catch ex As Exception`

Comment: I guess you're talking about C#. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your code as such:

```
Try
  (your code here)
Catch ex As FormatException
  (your exception handler)
End Try
```

This will catch only FormatException type exceptions. As you can see in this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/hf9z3s65(v=vs.110).aspx in the reference for the method in MSDN you always have information of the type of exceptions it throws.

For more information about exception handling see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/fk6t46tz.aspx